# Doing something in one breath

Tags: halacha, minhag, hefsek-interruption

I am looking to make a list of halachot/minhagim that involve doing something in 1 breath so I can see if I can draw any connections between them. So far, I have 3 things:

the [shevarim-tru'ah](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Print.asp?ClipID=2383) (or at least the shevarim)

the aseret bnei haman ([megillah 16b](http://dafyomi.co.il/megilah/points/mg-ps-016.htm))

the 15 praises in Yishtabach ([according to the shlah](http://www.torah.org/learning/tefilah/pausing.html))

Are there other mitzvot/halachot/minhagim that require that we do or say something in one breath? (I don't mean "within the time of" but actually IN one breath)

Comment: Don't forget the stanzas of Chad Gadya, Mi Yodeya, and Adir Hu!

Comment: [Related.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140061/saying-yishtabach-in-one-breath)

Answer (score 2):

[Rambam Hilchos Yibum V'Chalitza 4:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/4304.htm) says that the lady is supposed to be able to say Lo Ava in one breath.